# How to export File Names (Only Image Files) from various location or directory into a text file

Tags: command-line, filenames

As mentioned in the title, I need to export the file names of various image files from various directories into a single text file as a list. How would I go about doing such a task?

Secondly, would it be possible to partially remove the files names listed in the text file? Please see the screenshot:

[image]

I need to remove the filename "HS3-HTS-" and leave only the number for the filename.

Finally, would  I require command prompt to execute this task or is there another solution?

I found a [link](http://www.awdesigns.com/blog/2009/12/how-to-export-filenames-into-a-text-file/) here, but it did not tell how to select only image files, any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want file extensions jpg, jpeg, gif, and png; and assuming you want to pull the filenames from the current directory:

```
powershell "dir *.jpg,*.jpeg,*.gif,*.png | ForEach-Object {echo ($_.BaseName -replace 'HS3-HTS-', '')}" > Output.txt
```

If recursive searching is needed, to find files in multiple directories using a single command, the following may work (simply replace "C:\" with the desired drive or base directory):

```
powershell "Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Recurse -Include *.jpg,*.jpeg,*.gif,*.png | ForEach-Object {echo ($_.BaseName -replace 'HS3-HTS-', '')}" > Output.txt
```

Note that both of the above examples will put the list into a file called "Output.txt" located in the current directory. By *current directory*, I mean the directory being viewed using the Command Prompt. If you would like to see the output at the Command Prompt directly without having to open a file, simply omit the final `> Output.txt` in the above commands. Also note that despite being based on PowerShell, the above commands were formulated to run at the normal Command Prompt. The "powershell" part tells it to parse the command using PowerShell.